# Node.js Request Stream with Resume Support

Tags: javascript, node.js, request

I am using Node.js Request module to server Big Files form remote server.

Here is Code i use :

```
expressjs_app.get("/myFile_url", function(req, res){

   request.get('remote_file_url').pipe(res);

});
```

Problem i have , is Download like doesn't support Resume , when it pause its start form over.

source like dose support resume capability.

Answer (score 2):

To be able to serve partial content to clients you have to implement [HTTP Byte serving](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_serving). You could do this by hand but you'd be hacking reverse proxy functionality in your request handler. It would save time and effort, and prevent bugs, to have this done by an actual reverse proxy module or application.

I suggest giving the module [httpp-proxy](https://github.com/InstantWebP2P/node-httpp-proxy) or its parent project [http-proxy](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy) a try for passing the file instead of request. I can't say for sure whether it supports proxying byte ranges but I'd say there's a good chance it does.